# Twitter API get user info

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, sttwitter

Had many same question, but I also cannot find the solution for me. I decide to post the question. My app for users login by Twitter then tried to get user info, but always get the error. I used **STTwitter**. Here is my code:

```
  - (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier
{
    __weak typeof (self)weakself = self;
    self.twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:Twitter_API_KEY consumerSecret:Twitter_API_SECRET];
    [self.twitterAPI postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier
                                      successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {
                                          [weakself.twitterAPI getUserInformationFor:screenName
                                                                        successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user) {
                                                                            ///we have an account
                                                                            NSLog(@"something");
                                                                        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                            /// error
                                                                            NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
                                                                        }];

                                      } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                          ///error
                                          NSLog(@"Error:%@", error);
                                      }];
}
```

After user authorized, I can get the `token` and `oauth_verifier` then can passed into the function above. But I get the error:

```
Error:Error Domain=STHTTPRequest Code=401 "HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized" UserInfo=0x7f84c1531420 {NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized}
```

I also tried with the code below:

```
   self.twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:Twitter_API_KEY consumerSecret:Twitter_API_SECRET];
[self.twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
    NSLog(@"");
    [self.twitterAPI getUserInformationFor:@"jac_ln" successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user) {
        NSLog(@"");
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"EROR:%@", error);
    }];
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR:%@", error);
}];
```

But also cannot get user info from twitter.please help me.

Comment: Only the second snippet makes sense to me. Now if it keeps on returning status 401, check the consumer tokens and the clock of your device. If it still doesn't work, please explain exactly on which line you don't see what you expect, and what is expected for you exactly.

Answer (score 0):

[App_Delegate.twitter getUserInformationFor:[NS_Defaults objectForKey:kUserScreenName] successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user)
     {

```
     [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

     NSLog(@"Uesr Info-- %@", user);
     NSDictionary  *dictUser = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[[user objectForKey:@"name"],[user objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]] forKeys:@[kUserName,kUserProfileImage]];


     [NS_Defaults setObject:dictUser forKey:kUserInfo];

     [NS_Defaults synchronize];

     UIStoryboard *objStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
     App_Delegate.mainVC =[objStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:App_Delegate.mainVC animated:YES];
     [NS_Defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isLogin"];
     [NS_Defaults synchronize];


 } errorBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error-- %@", error);
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set a callback URL, even a simple string.